# Primefaces datatable with commandLink conflicts with row selection

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am working with PrimeFaces 5. The row selection is enabled and I want to embed a commandLink in one of the columns. When I click on the commandLink, I show a dialog, but I do not want the row to be selected. Is this possible (currently both events happen, the dialog is shown and the row is selected)?

```
                <p:dataTable id="tableData" widgetVar="tableData" var="p"
                         value="#{bean.list}" ...
                         selection="#{bean.selectedItem}" selectionMode="single">
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{actionBean.onSelect}"
                        update="@form" onstart="PF('statusDialog').show();"
                        oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide();" />

                <p:column headerText="Title" ...>
                    <p:commandLink id="clickableTitle" onstart="PF('statusDialog').show();"
                                   oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide();PF('detailsDialog').show()">
                        <h:outputText value="#{p.title}" styleClass="link"/>
                    </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>
```

Comment: Tried a newer version?

Comment: I'm using PrimeFaces 5.2. I need to stick with this version for now.

Comment: If you TRY with 5.3 and it works there, you can compare relevant sources and maybe create a patch…